# Combine two field in email field

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

laravel

I'm struggling to put the result of two **concatme** fields in another field input.
I would like to put the results of **response** in the email field input.

The thing I would like to achieve is to make it easier for the user to log in to the system without putting the whole email address john@box.domain.com.

here is the code so far.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

            @include('auth/banner')

            <div class="panel panel-default panel-shaded">
                
                <div class="panel-body">

                    @action('login_form.before')

                    <form class="form-horizontal margin-top" method="POST" action="{{ route('login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ __('Email Address') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
 
                                <!-- SCRIPT -->
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                  function concatme()
            {
                var num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
                var num2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
                document.getElementById("response").innerText = num1 + '' +num2;
            }
            </script>
                                <!-- FIN SCRIPT -->
                                <!---- INICIO---->
                                <input type="text" name="num1" class="form-control" id="num1" placeholder="USER">
                                 <input type="text" name="num2" class="form-control" id="num2" value="@box.domain.com" placeholder="Number 2">
                                <!---FIN-->
                                <!-- RESUTLADO PREVIEW -->
                                <p id="response"></p>
                                <!-- RESULDADO PREVIEW -->
                                
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <label class="checkbox">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> {{ __('Remember Me') }}
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" onclick="concatme()" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Login') }}
                                </button>

                                @if (Eventy::filter('auth.password_reset_available', true))
                                    <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ route('password.request') }}">
                                        {{ __('Forgot Your Password?') }}
                                    </a>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <p>Hola</p>

                    @action('login_form.after')
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I think its working but you are not able to see it because you have use form and called javascript function on submit button.
What happens is its sending request to given route and refreshing page thats make paragraph tag to empty again. Remove type submit from submit button and then confirm if its working or not.